# Test for the object with the biggest x-vector using python

Tags: python

I am trying to get the object out of bpy.data.objects with the biggest x-vector but i cant figure out the code.

Comment: I take it from your answer "biggest" is furthest right, eg (0, 0, 0) is bigger than (-1000, 0, 0), whereas the latter is further from the origin.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without constructing an auxillary dictionary, in one line:

```
biggest = max(bpy.context.scene.objects, key=lambda ob: ob.location.x)
```

The `key` parameter makes `max()` return the item from `bpy.context.scene.objects` with the largest `location.x` property.

Answer (score 0):

```
#Add empty dictionary
x_vectors = {}

#Add objects with related x-vector to dictionary
for o in bpy.data.objects:
  x_vectors[o] = o.location[0]

#Get the object with the biggest x-vector-key from the dictionary
biggestXVectorObject = max(x_vectors, key=x_vectors.get)
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, I think it would be helpful to include some explanation of the code and why it is the answer.

Comment: @Ray Mairlot to be honest: i just answered my own question. I just didnt remember the login data of my account so i just used my google one :)

Comment: @froggyman even so (and answering your own question is great) please add more information to it so that others can learn from it.